# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of AB and BA, proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is an $n \times k$ matrix and $B$ is an $k \times n$ matrix.

If $v_1, ..., v_l$ are linearly independent eigenvectors of $BA$ corresponding to a single nonzero eigenvalue $c$, then $Av_1, ..., Av_l$ are linearly independent eigenvectors of $AB$ corresponding to $c$.

I need help proving this.

Comment: Be careful with notation: you use the letter $k$ to represent two different things.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you prove some part of the question? (Notice there are two statements to prove)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What happens if you left-multiply the equation $BAv_i=kv_i$ with $A$?